# DirectionsRenderer disable on click GMaps v3

Tags: dojo, google-maps-api-3

I have a DirectionsRenderer sitting inside a Dojo ContentPane.

When I click on a step in the directions, it zooms into the wrong area.

Can I disable this or fix the boundaries so it works properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the API to zoom to the wrong area when infowindows are disabled.  I reenabled them and the zooming works.